# How can I change IIS Express 8.0 install directory so it doesn't use "My Documents"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2012, iis-express

Is it possible to change `IIS Express 8.0` so that its install and configuration directory is not under "My Documents"?

In our environment, "My Documents" is mapped to a network share.

The problem is that this makes local development in `Visual Studio .NET 2012` dependent on being on the network.

When I run my `ASP.NET MVC 4` application in `Visual Studio .NET 2012`, it spins up `IIS Express 8.0`.

To be quite honest, I'm not sure how `IIS Express 8.0` originally got on my development machine.  I did not install it directly.  However, I have installed both `Visual Studio .NET 2012` and `Microsoft WebMatrix 2.0` and suspect it came with one (or both) of these.

I tried uninstalling `IIS Express 8.0` from `Programs and Features`, going to [Microsoft Download Center - IIS 8.0 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34679), downloading `iisexpress_8_0_RTM_x64_en-US.msi`, and reinstalling it.

However, during the install process, I did not see any options for selecting an installation directory.

If anyone has any experience on changing this, I would be very appreciative of advice or insight.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, I think the answer is: this can't be done...yet.

I wanted this myself, so I dug deep into Process Monitor to see if there was some key or file config that could control it. It looks like that key is: HKCU\Software\Microsoft\IISExpress\CustomUserHome (REG_SZ). You can set this to your own custom path on your local drive, and IISExpress will honour it perfectly.

Alas, Visual Studio doesn't use it properly. I think this is a bug. ProcMon shows Visual Studio (briefly) making use of the CustomUserHome entry, but then still going and looking for necessary config files in the %UserProfile%\IISExpress\config\ folder.

Thus, if you were to try this fix (with the as-of-now current Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 at least), it might sorta look like it's working, but in reality it's still using the same %UserProfile%\IISExpress\config\ folder. If you delete or move that folder, your project won't even open at all.

If there's a way to tell Visual Studio what IISExpress user directory to use, I haven't found it, but would be happy to be enlightened.

This blog post shows a somwhat-similar situation affected by the same bug: http://areaofinterest.wordpress.com/2012/11/13/vs2012-iisexpress-migration-of-domainuser-and-network-share-wtf/

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that this makes local development in Visual Studio .NET
>   2012 dependent on being on the network.

You might want to try a different approach to solving this problem.

Make the `Documents\IIS Express` folder on the network share `"Always available offline"`. This uses the Offline Storage feature of Windows to locally cache the network folder and bi-directionally sync changes whenever the network share is available.

In fact, it's probably better to make the entire Documents folder `"Always available offline"` to avoid potential problems with other applications that store their user data there and expect that data to always be available.